# Which professions/backgrounds can make better slaves for an improved alien society in case of a selective termination?

Tags: science-fiction, aliens, civilization, population

Let's say that an advanced alien society somehow annexed or conquered earth for its natural resources. Then they discovered that these "human"s consume so much resources and they need to be removed from their new territory. However, instead of removing the whole species, they go with a more pragmatic decision and do this removing selectively. If a human is creating a "surplus", meaning they somehow create more value to the planet or the aliens then they consume, they will let you live in exchange for your service to them. People from which backgrounds do you think are most likely to survive?

For clarification & ease of answering, let's say this invaders are a type-I civilization that is near type-II, which means that they need our planet since they cannot consume our sun. Also, they have perfectly fine machinery/robotics so they don't need any muscle power from us.

Comment: What do the words *"create more value **for the planet**"* even mean? The planet is a piece of rock and iron, it does not have "values". And, the aliens being alien, it would be very difficult to assign utility functions to them -- they would probably not find value in what *we* find value.

Comment: @AlexP I presume value has to do with production of the natural resources mentioned earlier in the question.

Comment: It really depends on what the aliens consider valuable resource: they may have come for the iron or manganese (unlikely but whatever) but they may also discover that they also like human music or dancing or tagliatelle alla bolognese. So a composer, a dancer, a cook may be seen valuable. It really is up to your story.

Comment: @AlexP by saying that, I meant "to generate more output from the planet than consumed", which is indeed more value for **aliens**, I see why it is vague.

Comment: @DuncanDrake I didn't have the cultural things on my mind while asking, but they also seem to be likeable, at least to us. Your comment enlarged my perspective. Thanks!

Comment: As written, this is unanswerable. Productivity has something to do with background, but only so much. I've met highly educated, not-self-motivated people - and they're not productive. I've met uneducated highly-motivated people who produce gangbusters, but how valuable is a ditch? In a sense, what more answer than you need than "kill all the lazy people?" If you want something better, you need to clearly explain why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Depends on what the aliens think is valuable**

It is unclear what kind of resources they want from earth. It's likely food, resources like metal and sand or straight up labour.

For food it'll be people able to farm. Simple as that. Depending on how ecological sustainable they want to farm, you need few or a lot of people. Unsustainable is most often uniculture growing and can be done with high tech equipment nowadays. This can tell where it's best to plant what and what is required in water and nutrients day by day. This needs few highly educated farmers. The other are more ecologically sustainable, mixing a lot of food and livestock in an area. It'll be more labour intensive to maintain and high tech is less viable, though not completely. To maintain either way you'll probably want some management above to make sure there is adequate supply of each food. Creating food is currently heavily dependent on fossil fuel, so this would be also required to maintain farming. Lots can theoretically be taken over by electric variants, so you can use solar and such, but part of the human food processing always requires a bit of fossil fuels or oils (sunflower, olive, etc.). During the creation of fuel, a lot of by products are created that are useful in a myriad of ways, like greasing of engines.

To create useful stuff from oil, you'll need maintenance, monitoring and transport. To get to oil, you'll need oil rigs in the sea and on land. These again need maintenance, monitoring and transport.

Mining is probably obvious. You'll need people doing the operating of machinery and some management and transport.

Finally you need the creation of all the equipment. If it isn't given to the people by
the aliens, you'll need to have people create it. But if you create things, you'll probably want to improve it too. Improve creation processes and the material itself. Things so less people are required for the jobs.

You'll want some entertainment and luxury too, or else the humans are not as efficient.

Then finally you might want people able to talk with the aliens, being able to interpret any cultural differences and translating it to humans.

Depending on what you want, you can have a fully functioning society, though smaller than currently. Or you'll cut away nearly everything if you can supply a lot with alien technology and automation.

Comment: _You'll want some entertainment and luxury too, or else the humans are not as efficient._ Do you really think people are not as efficient without them? I mean, their lives kinda depend on their productivity. 
Other than that, great perspective, thanks!

Comment: @iamonur Yeah pretty sure. Even if your life depends on it, if you don't have any relief your productivity will slacken. Even just being mildly unhappy makes your productivity go down. If it gets worse with depression or other things like revolt or just working against the oppressors in small ways. Following things to the exact letter and such.

Comment: yeah I think I got it. Thanks for your response, I'm marking it.